# How to pass props from a container component to a class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying to separate the logic from class component to container component, so that class component only takes the responsibility of rendering html.
So, I have two components here one is **Home** which is a class component and another is **Home Container** which holds the code for **Home** component i.e, mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps.

Here are the files:
**Home.js:**

```
 render(){
        // Maps over 'items'
        let itemList = this.props.items.map((item) => {
            return (
                <div className="card" key={item.id}>
                    <img className="card-img-top" src={item.img} alt={item.title} />
                    <div className="card-body">
                        <span className="card-title">{item.title}</span>
                        <span to="/" onClick={() => {this.handleClick(item.id)}}><i className="material-icons">add</i></span>
                    </div>

                    <div className="card-content">
                        <p>Price: {item.price}</p>
                        {/* <p>{item.quantity}</p> */}
                    </div>

                </div>
            )
        })
        return(
            <div className="container">
                <h3 className="text-center">Our items</h3>
                <div className="box">
                    {itemList}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

which gets the props from container component and that is

**HomeContainer.js:**

```
class HomeContainer extends React.Component {
    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <Home items={this.props.items}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        items: state.items
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        addToCart: (id) => {dispatch(addToCart(id))}
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(HomeContainer)
```

and I am passing props to the **Home** in the **HomeContainer**.

When I am trying to access those props in the **Home** component by mapping over the items I am getting **Cannot read property of undefined**. How can I solve this issue.

Comment: `Cannot read property of undefined.`, which property exactly?

Comment: You may have to check that your `this.props.items.length` is > 0 before mapping over the array. The items array may not have been initialized on the first render of your component, that's why it's currently `undefined`.

Comment: can you please show what exactly error is throwing in browser toolbar

Comment: It is the **map** function that is undefined. **Cannot read property map of undefined.**

Comment: It is the **map** property that is undefined on the items array.